# Unable to store Array of values to single db table column in rails 2.x?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

Html code is:

```
Utilities: <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="amenity[utilities][]" value="Gas">Gas<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="amenity[utilities][]" value="Electricity">Electricity<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="amenity[utilities][]" value="Water">Water<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="amenity[utilities][]" value="Parking">Parking<br>
```

The above html is storing data in DB Table column as below:

```
--- 
- Gas
- Electricity
- Parking
- Water
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is because Rails serialize objects to YAML in order to store it in database. What you are seeing is actually  a YAML serialized array. Here:

```
require 'yaml'
dbstr = "--- 
- Gas
- Electricity
- Parking
- Water"
# => "--- \n- Gas\n- Electricity\n- Parking\n- Water"
YAML::load dbstr
# => ["Gas", "Electricity", "Parking", "Water"]
```

Also check the doc for [`ActiveRecord::Base#serialize`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize)